# Where did the other survivors come from?

Tags: future-boy-conan

In the TV series **Future Boy Conan**, a massive war left the Earth in shambles and humans tried to flee the planet on space ships, except they all failed except for one that managed to crash on an island that somehow survived the destruction. All of the survivors eventually died except for Conan, who was born after the space ship crashed, and his grandfather.

Then a girl named Lana washes up on shore and talks about this entire country of people. If the Earth was destroyed and all the other space ships didn't make it, where did these people come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The war involved WMDs which destabilised the earth's magnetic core leading to massive earthquakes and tsunamis which led to the sinking of most major land masses and general planetary destruction. Some small islands (islets) did survive and survivors flocked to them.

The two belligerents of the war were the Peace Union and the West with the former being the aggressive warmongers who used said WMDs and the latter the more peaceful bunch. Industria and High Harbour are the respective post-apocalyptic remnants of these two powers which retain their ideologies.

The anime is based on [Alexander Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Key)'s 1970 novel, [The Incredible Tide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Incredible_Tide). The linked wiki page has a decent synopsis of the story.

Comment: *Very* loosely based. The anime took the major plot line of the book but little else.